# Flutter, Dart: How to loop through a generated list in dart to get all the elements outside of the function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hey guys I am new to Flutter and Dart and trying to wrap my head around to get this variation selector working for the past 2 days. How to get both the items from the generated list(second one) outside of the generate function? I am only getting the first item.

This is the code.

```
List.generate((model.sizeColour.isNotEmpty) ? model.ss.length : model.size.length , (index) {
var sizeList;
if(model.sizeColour.isNotEmpty || model.sizeColour.length > 0) {
    if(model.selectedColour != null && model.selectedColour != ""){
    var _res = model.sizeColour
        .where((element) =>
            element.var2!.toUpperCase() == model.selectedColour)
        .toList();

    // _res contains 2 sizes for the selected colour.

    List.generate(_res.length, (i) {
    sizeList = _res[i];
    // This new list got both sizes
    });
    
    print(sizeList.varName);
    // Here I am getting only one. How to loop through the list to get both items?
    return buildSize(sizeList);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not really sharing enough code here but in general you could create a `Map<String, List>  {'res' : _res, 'sizeList' : sizeList}` and send that where ever you need both lists.

Comment: Ok..I will try that way. Thank you